# Apache Common IO FileUtils Issue

Tags: apache, apache-commons, fileutils

I am trying to use the FileUtils.writeStringToFile() method of the Apache Commons IO.  Every bit of documentation says that I can do this:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File, String with data, boolean append);
```

I want this method, because I want the data to be written to the end of the file each time.

However, in Eclipse, it keeps telling me that this method does not exist.  The only two I have are:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File, String with data);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File, String with data, String encoding);
```

I corrected my POM file to now have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Version [1.3.2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.3/index.html) doesn't have this method, use a newer version of commons-io

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Check the [FileUtils 2.4 javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Comment: I replaced the old dependency in my POM file with this one.  I am still having the same problem.  It says that the method with the boolean doesn't exist.

Comment: Check your Maven dependencies under eclipse to confirm that your project are using the 2.4 version also run the Maven Update Project, forcing to update dependences or execute a project clean.

Comment: When I run Maven Install, it is putting "commons-io-2.4.jar" into the Target folder.  I also ran Update Project.  I am STILL having the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way to tell what is wrong with your environment, I can only guarantee that the method you want to use is available in version 2.4. I would suggest a conflict of libraries but this should not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was adding the Tomcat library files as well as the JRE library files to my project.  Because when I deleted commons-io from my POM, I still had FileUtils available.

I had to get rid of the Tomcat library files from my build path, and once I put commons-io back in, it worked.